# When do people say 祝你工作快乐?

Tags: phrase

What does 祝你工作快乐 mean in Chinese and when do people use this phrase?

I googled it, but I couldn't find out when it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We never use 祝你工作快乐.

In the Chinese point of view, work is hard and a serious thing; you can use 勤劳 to describe hard-working people.

快乐 is more like to describe entertainment, so we don't use this word for work. If you want to express that someone is happy at work, you should say words like 乐在其中, if you want to wish someone's work to be good you should say 工作顺利

Answer (score 6):

祝你工作快乐 means "Hope you find joy/happiness in your work/job."

You can't find out when to use it. Probably it's because a more proper wording would be "祝你工作愉快" which is still rarely used. The most common term is "顺利" and therefore "祝你工作顺利" is more popular.

Maybe most traditional Chinese in the past, instead of finding joy from work, would prefer to conquer obstacles. "顺利" means smoothly, successfully or favorably. The use of "祝你" starts a condition of formal wishes in general. Then "愉快" is a term more formal than "快乐." But again, people usually say "工作顺利" for the sake of one's job.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is very Chinese, maybe an Anglicism.

If you say to me:

“I have to go to work.”
“我得去上班儿。”

my English reply, somewhat sarcastically, may be:

Have fun! (Work is not always 'fun'.)

You might render that as:
工作快乐！

But I think the normal Chinese reply would be:

好的。

迎财神！祝你发大财！

Comment: Can you imagine wishing a Chinese actor about to give a performance -- "Break a leg"? :)

Comment: In German you wish "break your neck and a leg"!! I doubt the Chinese use that expression either!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to China and say 祝你工作快乐 to express your wish you would suffer  a very "hearty" response .Such as: CNM.
Consequently,I feel people can't say 祝你工作快乐 to express own wish in every situation expect you want to express some sarcastic words